# I don't understand what makes questions acceptable

Tags: request

I'm confused about what qualifies a question as something that is allowed on this site. Can someone explain what specific kinds of questions are allowed with examples?

I've tried to look for patterns in questions very carefully, both acceptable and unacceptable, to try to find a rhyme or reason.

Comment: This is a discussion for meta.stackoverflow.com . But when you ask a question there's a highlighted box with a link to this site: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic which broadly answers the question.

Comment: I read that and it didn't answer my question.